# Regression output and Fisher-Snedecor distribution

Tags: regression

I'm working on regression models in STATISTICA application and I need to know what is Fisher-Snedecor distribution for and how to analyze my regression model in this distribution. 
What the significance level means? What is v1 and v2? I need an explanation and little tutorial on real data.

Comment: Maybe Wikipedia will be sufficient here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#Regression_problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fisher Snedecor distribution is another name for the [F-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution). The F-distribution comes from the ratio of two chi-squared variables.

In regression, you use the F-distribution in the [ANOVA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) table. This table gives you information about which variables/covariates should be in your model.

The v1 and v2 are called the degrees of freedom. In simple linear regression,o.e.

Y = a + bx + epsilon

we have a single extra variable. So v1 = p = 1 and v2 = n-p-1 = n-2.

I don't use STATISTICA, so I can't give you more detailed information.